# Regex to get first number in string with other characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regular expressions, and was wondering how I could get only the first number in a string like `100 2011-10-20 14:28:55`. In this case, I'd want it to return `100`, but the number could also be shorter or longer.

I was thinking about something like `[0-9]+`, but it takes every single number separately (100,2001,10,...)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the string always starts with a number or do you want the first number from any string? If it's the former, this **is not a good use of regular expressions**.

Comment: I know the string always starts with a number. It always follows the pattern I gave. (value date time)

Comment: Why not just look for the first space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this to match for first number in string (which can be not at the beginning of the string):

```
    String s = "2011-10-20 525 14:28:55 10";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)([0-9]+)($|\\s)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 30):

```
/^[^\d]*(\d+)/
```

This will start at the beginning, skip any non-digits, and match the first sequence of digits it finds

EDIT:
this Regex will match the first group of numbers, but, as pointed out in other answers, parseInt is a better solution if you know the number is at the beginning of the string

Comment: This regex worked for me (regExr and Python) to match the first digits regardless what comes before: 
`/[^\d]*(\d+)/`

Answer (score 9):

Just

```
([0-9]+) .*
```

If you always have the space after the first number, this will work

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there's always a space between the first two numbers, then

```
preg_match('/^(\d+)/', $number_string, $matches);
$number = $matches[1]; // 100
```

But for something like this, you'd be better off using simple string operations:

```
$space_pos = strpos($number_string, ' ');
$number = substr($number_string, 0, $space_pos);
```

Regexs are computationally expensive, and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: This Java syntax looks odd to me.  Please include links to the Java documentation for me.

Answer (score 2):

the below code would do the trick.

```
Integer num = Integer.parseInt("100 2011-10-20 14:28:55");
```

Comment: +1 pending if the string *always* starts with a number... Also it's `Integer.parseInt()` :)

Comment: This is a more straightforward solution based on the user's confirmation that the string always starts with the desired number. For the kids at home, **no need for a regular expression.** Compare this code to the *answer*, nuff said.

Comment: NumberFormatException is thrown in this case.

Comment: According to the docs:

`The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value`

Answer (score 1):

[0-9] means the numbers 0-9 can be used the + means 1 or more times. if you use [0-9]{3} will get you 3 numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try `^(?'num'[0-9]+).*$` which forces it to start at the beginning, read a number, store it to 'num' and consume the remainder without binding.

Answer (score 1):

This string extension works perfectly, even when string not starts with number.
return 1234 in each case - "1234asdfwewf", "%sdfsr1234" "## # 1234"

```
    public static string GetFirstNumber(this string source)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source) == false)
        {
            // take non digits from string start
            string notNumber = new string(source.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) == false).ToArray());

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(notNumber) == false)
            {
                //replace non digit chars from string start
                source = source.Replace(notNumber, string.Empty);
            }

            //take digits from string start
            source = new string(source.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
        }
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: this is not java, why is this here?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: In Java, when you define the patterns as string literals, do not forget to use double backslashes to define a regex escaping backslash (`\.` = `"\\."`).

To get the *number that appears at the start or beginning of a string* you may consider using

```
^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+       # Float or integer, leading digit may be missing (e.g, .35)
^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+     # Optional - before number (e.g. -.55, -100)
^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+  # Optional + or - before number (e.g. -3.5, +30)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WSQhdW/2).

If you want to also match numbers with scientific notation at the start of the string, use

```
^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?        # Just number
^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?      # Number with an optional -
^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?   # Number with an optional - or  +
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WSQhdW/1).

To make sure there is no other digit on the right, add a `\b` word boundary, or a `(?!\d)` 
 or `(?!\.?\d)` negative lookahead that will fail the match if there is any digit (or `.` and a digit) on the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str=s.nextLine();
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
        Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group()+" ");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`\d+`

`\d` stands for any decimal while `+` extends it to any other decimal coming directly after, until there is a non number character like a space or letter