# Regex splitting by first number

Tags: javascript, regex

Note: This is NOT a duplicate of [Regex to get first number in string: 100 2011-10-20 14:28:55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854123/regex-to-get-first-number-in-string-100-2011-10-20-142855) (only works when the string starts with a number).

Say I have the following input. The distribution of letters and numbers can be completely random. Additionally, it may contain other characters such as `- / ?` etc..

```
'ONEac123TWO45THREEabc67FOUR89bcFIVE'
```

What I need is an array in the form:

```
[everything before the first number, the first number, everything else]
```

So for my example, that would be:

```
['ONEac','123','TWO45THREEabc67FOUR89bcFIVE']
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So, what have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.match` to get your result.

```
> 'ONEac123TWO45THREEabc67FOUR89bcFIVE'.match(/^(\D*)(\d+)(.*)$/).slice(1)
  ["ONEac", "123", "TWO45THREEabc67FOUR89bcFIVE"]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
^(\D+)(\d+)(.+)$
```

http://rubular.com/r/kMhyKH3Sbd

```
^            start of string
(\D+)        match anything that is not a digit into one group (1 or more, use * for 0 or more)
(\d+)        match 1 or more digits into another group (I am assuming you want ints)
(.+)         match whatever is left into another group
$            end of string
```

Comment: What operation is that? .split()?

Comment: @Kvothe: What operation is what. It's a regex. You can look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to see how to use it.