# How to tease out an integer value from each element in an array in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell

I have an array of folder names using the following code

```
 [Array]$j = Get-ChildItem J:\Samarth_Runs_CRCM\1_Banks | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '_' }
```

Output of this array is the following

```
 Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 ----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 d----        11/23/2016   5:34 PM            Point1_output                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 d----        11/23/2016   3:59 PM            Point2_output                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 d----        11/10/2016   1:07 PM            Point3_output                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 d----        11/10/2016   1:07 PM            Point4_output                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 d----        11/10/2016   1:07 PM            Point5_output
```

For each element in `$j` I would like to tease out an integer value. For example, I want an output to be 1 for Point1_output, 2 for Point2_output and so on..
I used the following code to extract the desired output

```
 Foreach ($d in $j){
            $d.Substring(5,1)
         }
```

I received following error

```
 Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'Substring'.
```

Desired output

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

I do not know how to get around this.

Answer: I apologize for the trouble and I would like to thank you to those who took time to comment on this. I do believe that there is more efficient way of going around this problem but for now the following answer will suffice.

```
 [string]$j = Get-ChildItem J:\Samarth_Runs_CRCM\1_Banks | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '_' }

 $k = $j -split ' '

 Foreach ($d in $k){
           $d.Substring(5,1)
     }
```

Comment: Hi Samarth, have you thought of using Regex? To get first number in a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854123/regex-to-get-first-number-in-string-100-2011-10-20-142855   /^[^\d]*(\d+)/ is what they are saying. I'm only new to Regex so not much more help than searching online. Don Jones also has an article here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.11.powershell.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $matches which can be used with multiple items, but evaluate each item individually.
But if you still want to use the substring directly on the context; Please try making it to tostring first because System.Object does not have any method substring.

```
$j = Get-ChildItem D:\Test | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '_' }|%{$_.Name.ToString().Substring(5,1)}
```

***OUTPUT:***
PS C:\Windows\system32> $j
1
2
3
4
5

Answer (score 0):

Forcing an array isn't neccessary.

```
$j = Get-ChildItem . -file  | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '(\d+)_' }|%{$matches[1]}
```

The `(\d+)_` in the where -match is a capture group reprenting at least one digit in front of the underscore. The following %=foreach outputs the found matches[1] aka the capture group, $matchhes[0] would be the whole match with underscore

Output

```
> $j
1
3
5
4
2
```